# Creating one Facebook page for two or more blogs

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I write two blogs, one in blogger and another in Wordpress. I found out that I can insert the blog URL in 'Notes' of a facebook page and import the posts. I was wondering if there is any way to post updates from two separate blogs into a single page automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to use Yahoo Pipes to do this...but I didn't do it right...I assume one could accomplish this by creating a combined feed and importing THAT feed in to your notes section.

I do not know how to do that though. but I am sure it is possible this way.

Comment: I could do it using Yahoo Pipes. I used the pipe URL and fed it into Notes > Import Link. But I noticed that feeds weren't fetched immediately by 'Notes'. Therefore now I use RSS Graffiti app to feed blogs to my Facebook page. It's simple as I just had to add two feeds.